# PIL.Image.save followed by PIL.Image.open doesn't work

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm using

`Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)` and `PIL.Image.VERSION = 1.1.7`

I have a saved tiff image that I can correctly open and view it using:

```
tiffIm = PIL.Image.open(tiffFileName)
tiffIm.show()
```

Now if I save the file this way:

```
tiffIm.save(saveFileName)
```

Then I can correctly open and view it using:

```
tiffImSaved = PIL.Image.open(saveFileName)
tiffImSaved.show()
```

However, if I save the file this way:

```
tiffIm.save(saveFileNameCompressionNone, compression="None")
```

Then I can't correctly open and view it using:

```
tiffImCompressionNone = PIL.Image.open(saveFileNameCompressionNone)
tiffImCompressionNone.show()
```

Note: when I open the image saved without specifying `compression="None"` the mode attribute is `F` (i.e. tiffImSaved.mode = 'F').  But when I save the image with specifying `compression="None"`, the mode attribute is `I` (i.e. tiffImCompressionNone.mode = 'I').

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in `compression=None` rather than `compression="None"`

Comment: I thought that would help since http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html in section on Saving Tiff Images shows it.

Comment: I tried & got error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1675, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1442, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, 'libtiff', a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 431, in _getencoder
    return encoder(mode, *args + extra)
TypeError: must be string, not None`